# How to access an environment variable from inside an object Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, variables, environment-variables

I'm having some issues trying to access a variable from inside of an object. I'm trying to access the 'APIKEY' variable from inside of the options object but this doesn't seem to work for me. I'd like to not have to hard code my api key from the .env file, but anything I've tried doesn't seem to work. I'd really appreciate any help :)

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"; 
import Header from "../components/headerTeamList";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TeamList from "../components/teamList";

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    padding: "20px",
  },
});

const HomePage = (props) => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [teams, setTeams] = useState([]);
  const APIKEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY

  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'X-RapidAPI-Key': APIKEY,
      'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com'
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api-football-v1.p.rapidapi.com/v3/standings/?season=2021&league=39', options)
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((json) => {
      console.log(json.response[0].league.standings[0])
      setTeams(json.response[0].league.standings[0])
    })
  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
}, []);

  return (
    <Grid container className={classes.root}>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Header title={"Home Page"} />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container spacing={5}>
        <TeamList teams={teams}></TeamList>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
};
export default HomePage;
```

Comment: `'X-RapidAPI-Key': APIKEY` should correctly set the api key in the header. Are you sure `process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY` actually fetches the env var? You could try by adding `console.log(APIKEY)` after `const APIKEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY`.

Comment: Hey @Jeroen Verfaillie, yes, I've tried this also and unfortunately it did not work. I'm definitely pulling back the correct data that  I need, based on the console.log but just cannot seem to add it to the headers object

Comment: Apologies @@Jeroen Verfaillie, after you mentioned it, I had another look and noticed that I for some reason had a comma in my .env file. Thank you for your help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This was a silly mistake on my part as I had a comma in my .env file that should not have been there